# DO NOT Acquire Target When Being Attacked

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm wondering if there is any way to disable the mildly annoying feature in which my character will automatically acquire the target of whatever is attacking him.

Ideally, I want to ignore whatever is hitting me - sticking to my primary target is preferred. Is this functionality possible?

Comment: Can you give more context? Who you target and when (are you in combat already), who attacks you and how, etc. I am not playing WoW currently, but I recall [focus target](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Focus_target) was useful in certain scenarios and I was macro addict.

Comment: Sure Sinatr, so, I play rogue and I plan on playing blood DK in Shadowlands; the next iteration of WoW. Since I play specs that are up close and personal...maybe, I could just make something which would automatically acquire and "sticky" a focus target.

Nowadays, Additonally, WoW has something in retail WoW called "Target Scanning" which is basically a different version of the (good ol') tab-targeting except the goal of scanning is to aim at whatever is in front you / your camera.

With all of that being said, the inherent problem (is) the target will switch if you are NOT attacking!

Comment: Are you still having problems with this? If you're in combat and have a target selected, when something else attacks you your target should not be changing. The only time I've ever seen a target acquired automatically is when I currently have nothing selected and I am attacked. If you could describe the exact scenario when this is happening we might be able to help better.